# Container wrapper shifts right

Tags: css, wordpress, containers, centering

I have taken over the management of a Wordpress website and am having troubles with positioning of #containerWrapper.

If the browser window is too small, the entire site shifts to the right so that it needs to be scrolled back into horizontal position in order to see it.

There is a content wrapper which includes a background shadow image and a second content container which contains the WP site.

Here is the CSS for both items:

```
#containerWrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1200px;
    background-image: url(images/container_shadows.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: center top;
} 

#container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1170px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

I need this entire content area to stay centered when browser window is resized. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does too small mean smaller than 1200px?

Comment: Although I didn't realize this when I asked the question, yes. The image shifts right when resized below 1200px.

Comment: I see that there is code written for screens less than 1200px. (below):

    @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) { 
    #containerWrapper {
    transform: scale(.82);
    -webkit-transform: scale(.82);
    -moz-transform: scale(.82);
    -ms-transform: scale(.82);
    -o-transform: scale(.82);
     position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -585px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 width: 1170px;
 transform-origin: top center;
 -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
 -moz-transform-origin: top center;
 -ms-transform-origin: top center;
 -o-transform-origin: top center;
}

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to get code to show properly in comments.

Comment: Took out "position:absolute" and it seems to be working now. 

Thanks for leading me in the right direction.